# How do I access the data from iframe in the parent window using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, iframe

I wanted to access the contents of iframe in the main (parent) window..using jQuery

```
    <iframe id="epsresponse" name="epsresponse" src="js/demo.json">
    </iframe>

    <button>click</button>

    <div id="atg_store_storedCreditCards">
    </div>
    </div>
```

I was trying with adding separate JSON file using Ajax jQuery its working fine,
I need the same thing when the JSON data are rendering inside the iframe.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         window.onload=function() {
            var iframeContent = $('#epsresponse').html();
            console.log(iframeContent);
         };
        $('button').live('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: 'js/demo.json',
                dataType:'json',
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.status == "success"){
                        console.log(data.nickname); 
                        console.log(data.token); 
                        console.log(data.expirationMonth); 
                        console.log(data.expirationYear); 
                        console.log(data.nameOnCard); 
                        console.log(data.creditCardNumber); 
                        console.log(data.creditCardType); 

                        $('#atg_store_storedCreditCards').append('<div class="atg_store_storedCreditCards"><div class="nickname">'+data.nickname+'</div><div class="token">'+data.token+'</div><div class="expirationMonth">'+data.expirationMonth+'</div><div class="expirationYear">'+data.expirationYear+'</div><div class="nameOnCard">'+data.nameOnCard+'</div><div class="creditCardNumber">'+data.creditCardNumber+'</div><div class="creditCardType">'+data.creditCardType+'</div></div>');
                        //<div class="token">'+data.token+'</div><div class="expirationMonth">'+data.expirationMonth+'</div><div class="expirationYear">'+data.expirationYear+'</div><div class="nameOnCard">'+data.nameOnCard+'</div><div class="creditCardNumber">'data.creditCardNumber+'</div><div class="creditCardType">'data.creditCardType+'</div>  
                        //$('#nickname').html('+ nickname +');          
                    }
                },
                error: function(status){
                    console.log(status);
                }
            });



        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: why would you have an iFrame of json? why not just load the jSon with ajax?

Comment: check out this [link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage). it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
var frameDoc = window.frames[ 0 ].document;
```

then you do `$(frameDoc).find( <<selector>> );`